# Детали issubclass

Tags: python

У меня есть любой класс:

```py
class SomeClass:
    ...
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при вызове `issubclass(SomeClass, dict)` возвращалось значение `True`.
При этом я не хочу использовать наследование.
То есть, мне не нужны решения такого типа:

```py
class SomeClass(dict):
    ...
```

**UPD:** *Решение через наследование будет считаться правильным, если подкласс не будет наследовать методы родительского класса.*

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать наследование? И в чём смысл вообще? Эта проверка как бы и проверяет наследование

Comment: По некоторым причинам я не могу использовать наследование. Ну, так уж получилось. Фактически мне нужно обмануть проверку наследования, я пытался сделать это через `__bases__`, но понял, что python его просто игнорирует и уперся в тупик. А вообще можно было бы попробовать через наследование, если есть способ удалить все методы родительского класса.

Comment: Зачем вы хотите создать запутанный и сложный код, который не поймёт никто кроме вас и за который вы будете сами себя проклинать в будущем?

Comment: Ой что-то там сложно всё https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/why-you-cant-remove-parent-methods-in-python-d4935e6d54a4

Comment: @CrazyElf у меня с классами и ооп все хорошо, у меня появилась нестандартная задача, я ее не смог решить, а мне кидают статью про наследование. Я говорю: без наследования.

Comment: Ну тогда выдумывайте через метаклассы что-нибудь "вручную"

Answer (score 1):

Задачу можно решить незамысловатым метаклассом, как отмечалось в комментариях, наследования в таком случае производится не будет. В момент создания класса в его bases-tuple будет подмешиваться dict.
Пример работы кода:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, clsname, clsbases, clsmethods):
        clsbases = (dict, *clsbases)
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, clsbases, clsmethods)


class A(metaclass=Meta):
    pass


print(issubclass(A, dict))
```

Вывод

```
True
```

Comment: Я тоже пытался так сделать, но мне нужно чтобы методы родительского класса не появлялись в моем подклассе. А ваше решение можно назвать наследованием

Comment: Возможно тогда вам поможет решение предложенное в этом вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181442/how-to-hide-remove-some-methods-in-inherited-class-in-python/23182583